# Image rotation around the lower right edge iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to rotate the Image around the lower right edge.

Now it rotates around the center.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0f/-800.0f; // perspective
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (M_PI * 90), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

if (animation)
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9
                     animations:^{
                         [[_sendRecordView layer] setTransform:transform];
                     } completion:NULL];
}
else
{
   [[_sendRecordView layer] setTransform:transform];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set this:

```
[_sendRecordView layer].anchorPoint = CGPointMake(X, Y);
```

where X and Y are the desired lower right edge point.

EDIT:
By default a view spins around the center because the anchorPoint is in that position.

Comment: I think the default is 0.5,0.5 - in the center. I tried that, and the view moved up and left.